# QTreeWidget expand sign

Tags: qt, pyqt

How to make expandable sign in QTreeWidget always visible even when item doest have any subitems? And how to draw something else instead of default sign?

Thanks in advance,
Serge

Comment: I don't know the answer to the second part of your question. (I recommend again to ask in a separat question.), but I think this is going to involve QTreeView and a delegate, that's probably a lot more work than just sticking to the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QTreeWidgetItems have the [property *childIndicatorPolicy*](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtreewidgetitem.html#setChildIndicatorPolicy). The allowed values are:

- QTreeWidgetItem::ShowIndicator
- QTreeWidgetItem::DontShowIndicator
- QTreeWidgetItem::DontShowIndicatorWhenChildless

You want the first one.

```
theItem.setChildIndicatorPolicy(QTreeWidgetItem.ShowIndicator)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped, and for the second part of my question - i found the solution myself

Comment: how do you hide indicator when it has child?

Answer (score 8):

Answering on my second part of question for others.

I looked for drawing functions in QTreeView and found following:

```
void QTreeView::drawBranches ( QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, const QModelIndex & index )
```

With this function you can draw whatever you want at the left side of each item.

And another good choice to hanlde this - use Style Sheets for QTreeView:

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview