# Change the column where the expander arrow is displayed in QTreeView

Tags: qt4, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I am using a `QAbstractItemModel` to store some data, and a `QTreeView` to display the information. I have been trying to move the expander arrow to the second column instead of having it in the first column, but I haven't been lucky. I tried to use a `QTableView` to see if I could define the behavior for each column, without success.  Any ideas?

Previously I was using `pygtk` to display a `TreeView`, and there is an easy way to define the columns where you want to have the expander arrow called `TreeView.set_expander_arrow()`

Comment: I assume you must mean `set_expander_column()`. However, for the benefit of those unfamiliar with pygtk, can you explain more clearly what this does (and/or provide a screenshot)?

Comment: The PyGTK function specifies which column of the treeview to place the expansion icon in (aka the + symbol to show/hide children).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily, but it is not immediately obvious how because `QTreeView` always displays the expander icons next to model column 0, and there is no way to change that. However, what you can do is change the order in which the model columns are displayed in the view, so model column 0 with its expander icons need not be at the very left.

Put the data you want to show to the *left* of the expander icons into model column 1 and the data you want to show to the *right* of the expander icons into model column 0. This is just the other way round as you would normally expect. Then, after populating the tree simply call `tree->header()->moveSection(1,0)` to move column 1 to the left of column 0.

Credits to Michael Durland who posted this solution on a Qt mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't have a native 'view' that allows you to specify which column the expand symbol is in. However, I believe with a little subclassing of QTreeView you can probably achieve what you want.

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641587/1994235) details how to draw something to the left of any item), so you could draw the symbol you wish and then overwrite [mouseReleaseEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#mouseReleaseEvent) to find if the area clicked is over one of your drawn symbols ([this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) will be of help)

Sorry I can't be more help than that, but it is quite a large task to implement the behaviour you want! (I'm currently porting a GTK project to Qt myself, so I may have to implement this at some point. If I ever do, I'll check back here and post my code!)